# Get data part by part in asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

My Data is Very huge So, I need to get data part by part to accelerate the page behavior .

I have this Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvValues" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"  
PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnRowCommand="gvValues_RowCommand"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" PageSize="15" 
     OnRowDataBound="gvValues_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvValues_PageIndexChanging" >
```

function

```
private void FillData()
{
    var pagesize = gvValues.PageSize;
    var pageindex = gvValues.PageIndex;
      products = ProductBLL.GetProductsByStoreIDcust(storeId, null,
                out totalRecords, pageindex, pagesize, keyword, txtSearchBarcode.Text);
    gvValues.DataSource = products;
    gvValues.DataBind();
}
```

this Function fill GridView in load and once again in

```
protected void gvValues_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvValues.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    this.FillData();
}
```

and this function gets data from database

```
public static List<Product> GetProductsByStoreIDcust(int? StoreID, ProductLocation? location , out int totalRecords, int itemsToSkip,
            int pageSize , string search = "", string barcode = "", string Relations = "no"             )
        { totalRecords = products.Count();
                if (products.Count() > 0)
                    return products.Skip(itemsToSkip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                else
                    return null;

        }
```

How can I get

```
var pageCount = query.Count();
```

Now this gridview display the First 15 item correctly,

but paging under gridview disappeared, what is missing in my code please help

Comment: Are you using server side pagination?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand you

Comment: Please check below link for custom paging It will solve your problem http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your page code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
              this.FillData();
        }
    }
```

Ok have a look at this [project](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f970c89cdf54b0f8287afd919563af4720160504100941/f39fa2#)

Comment: I already do that , I need to make custom paging, because gridview can't do its paging

Comment: This is a simple GridView, that is not I need, I need to make custom paging

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a query to get all records. So you have records number, page size and you can calculate number of pages. Using them you can build your own pager (using a repeater or pager control - from 3.5)

Then you can use your code to get records in current page.

I can suggest you can also use other plugin as https://datatables.net/

Comment: Do you mean I can't custom my gridview paging?

Comment: No, i don't.
You can find many articles to do it as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx 

You have also better methods today to do same thing. EG
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/

Comment: Thanks Alot seems that the last link it what I already need , but I change the mode of the `PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast"` and it works fine